# Determine log-normal parameters from graph

Tags: logarithms, normal-subgroups

I am attempting to recreate the log normal parameters given points on a "fitted" line.

This is my [Log-normal Distribution Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XZj6.png); it's from a study on lighting characteristics.

The axes on the graphs are scaled (log with base 10 on the amplitudes and a normal distribution on the probabilities).

These probabilities in percent: [2, 10, 50, 90, 98] %
correspond to the following amplitudes in kiloamps:  [140, 65, 20, 6.2, 3.1] kA

I do not have the raw data - only points on the fitted line are presented.

How do I determine the function for the fitted line?

Here is what I have tried:

I am want to go from the probabilities to the parameters: $\mu$, $\sigma$

$median = e ^ \mu$

The median is 20, so
$\mu= ln(20) = 2.9957$

There rest I have to use the lognormal quantile function:
$Q(p) = e^{\mu + \sigma\sqrt{2}erf^{-1}(2p-1)} $

where 0 ≤ p < 1.

My problem is I do not know how to solve the inverse error function. And am doubting this is the right path to solve for $\sigma$.

Can this community help me?

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this I used a "guess and check" method & python, the former is unsatisfying and the latter is out of scope for this community.

I used scipy module from python to determine the output of inverse error function.

Here is the code:

> import numpy as np
>
> import math
>
> from scipy import special   per = [98, 90, 50, 10, 2]
>
> first = [140, 65, 20, 6.2, 3.1]
>
> mu = np.log(first[2])
>
> y = [2*pp/100-1 for pp in per]
>
> Y = special.erfinv(y)
>
> guess = 0.947491
>
> check = [np.exp(mu+guess*math.sqrt(2)*yy) for yy in Y]

I adjusted my guess to get a values for check, which are close to my amplitudes (named first here).

There may be a numerical method to solve for sigma (aka guess) with minimal error for these points. But I don't know how to implement.